# Anguilla - Unable to populate item using minor verision

Tags: tridion

**How to populate an item using minor version?**
Am using the below code snippet.

`var item = $models.getItem('tcm:222-7244-64-v1');` - **Works fine.**

`var item = $models.getItem('tcm:222-7244-64-v1.3');` - **Throws error.**

I was able to get the minor version from DAL using below query as neither the CoreService nor Anguilla Framework provides it, but i need to populate the item using minor version. Could someone help me to resolve it?

```
select max(version)||'.'|| max(revision) as rev from items where item_reference_id='7244'
```